# Почему не срабатывает событие на карусели?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Почему событие "клик" на $('#wrapper') не срабатывает?

https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/16/

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    1000: {
      items: 1
    }
  }
});
$('#wrapper').click(function(){
alert(44);
})
```

```css
#element1,
#element2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel carousel1">
  <div class="item">

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="element1"></div>
      <div id="element2"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>13</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
$(document).on("click","#wrapper",function() {
  alert("Ваш текст");
});
```

Comment: Вот применил ваш метод для события "mousemove"https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/17/  Но не работает. PS если loop: false сделать то ок. но fals не надо

Comment: Попробуйте так `$('#wrapper').mousemove(function(event){
    тут Ваш код
});` Тут Вам нужно, что бы оно срабатывало на `wrapper` или на всем документе?

Comment: Измените и будет работать. `$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "#wrapper" ) ) {
     parallax(e, plane, 20);
     parallax(e, rocket, 29);
  }
});`

Comment: Только на wrapper. Вот - 18 строка: https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/19/

Comment: И даже так не работает https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/20/

Comment: Да, извините, исправьте `event` на `e` в` var target = $(e.target);`

Comment: Кажется тут не в этом дело а в структуре кода может? https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/22/

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS Обновил Ваш пример https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/24/ Загляните в консоль и поймете, что событие срабатывает там где нужно. Если что-то не работает, то в другом месте

Comment: Действительно событие срабатывает а элементы #element1,
#element2 не подвижные